# When echoing out html tags the output prints out everything

Tags: php, html

I want to apply the html tags to the variable.

Code: `echo '<strong>'.$message['sender'].' Sent'.'</strong>';`

Output: `<strong>The actual message Sent</strong>`

Desired output: **The actual message Sent**

How can i apply the strong class to the $message variable?

Full context code::

```
<textarea name="message" disabled  rows="6"  style="resize:none;" placeholder="Loading...">
<?php
    $messages = get_msg();
    foreach($messages as $message){
        echo '<strong>'.$message['sender'].' Sent'.'</strong>';
        echo $message['message'].'<br/><br/>';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        if(send_msg($_POST['sender'],$_POST['message'])){
            echo 'Message Sent.';
        }else{
            echo 'Message failed to send';
        }
    }
?>
</textarea>
```

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah well that's what i thought as well. But it doesnt for me.

 Added the full code.

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment about "worked for me" lol was trying to test fully, but not seeing full code, was unable to, which is why I deleted it.

Comment: can you post your complete html

Comment: one thing though, try replacing `disabled` with `readonly`, which may be a contributing factor to answer(s) given. POST arrays cannot modify inputs etc with `disabled`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need a `<textarea>` as this is output and not input.

Try using a simple `<div>` instead then the html tags like `<strong>` will work as you expect. Try this for example

```
<div>
<?php
    $messages = get_msg();
    foreach($messages as $message){
        echo '<strong>'.$message['sender'] .' Sent</strong><br/>';
        echo $message['message'].'<br/><br/>';
    }

    if(isset($_POST['send'])){
        if(send_msg($_POST['sender'],$_POST['message'])){
            echo '<span style="color=blue">Message Sent.</span>';
        }else{
            echo '<span style="color=red">Message failed to send</span>';
        }
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Riggs... [Seen my comment to the OP...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810656/when-echoing-out-html-tags-the-output-prints-out-everything#comment51546931_31810656). Might be worth noting ;-) I've seen that happen before. So, it "could" be an additional factor.

Comment: Yea but I dont see how he would make use of a `<textarea>` (the way he is using it) to allow for example a `re-send` of any message that had failed so this just has to be an output only requirement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- No sweat, I always pay attention to your comments.

Comment: ...and vice-versa ;-)

Comment: ok, convo saved, was too good not to. Let's delete from `Should we kiss now?...` on down... you too Sam @JayBlanchard before we get sent in the corner with DUNCE caps

Answer (score 4):

You are outputting HTML directly into a textarea. Textareas are plain text only, not rich text editors. More information regarding textareas can be found [Mozilla Developer Network documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)

May I suggest some Rich Text Editors (AKA WYSIWYG editors) such as [Redactor](http://imperavi.com/redactor/) or [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: No, any text input fields will be plain text online. You need to find a rich text editor.